# determining number of free threads

Tags: cpu, jobs, thread, multiprocessor

Suppose that on a computer capable of processing `n` simultaneous threads, one wishes to launch `n-m` single-thread jobs where `m` is the number of threads currently in use. How is `m` defined and by what means can its value be determined? For instance, on an unshared system with two sockets containing quad-core processors with SMT and no active processes beyond those ordinarily run by the system in the background, a user might launch 16 single-thread processes without worrying too much about process interference (cache misses, etc.). Can one simply consider the number of threads of each user-owned process? Given that processors can rapidly change threads, I assume the determination would involve more than that. Would a determination be better made by considering the total number of virtual cores and estimated overall CPU usage?

Comment: I'm not sure it works that way, unless I'm misunderstanding your question or the meaning of "thread"

Comment: @ILMostro_7: I was using the term in both the hardware and software senses. I would like to determine the number of available hardware threads or conversely the number of occupied hardware threads, which I suppose could be done by examining the software threads of user-owned processes.